# Uploading image to a server and saving its path in database using Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, image-uploading

I am quite new to ASP classic and have been assigned a task related to image uploading. What i have to do is that i need to upload the image file on server and then save its corresponding path in database. How to achieve this. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried something like FileUploader [http://aspuploader.com/ or http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/66294/Classic-ASP-ASP-File-Uploader]?

Comment: why didn't you store the image name in database and retrieve it as string,when you want to display it.

Comment: image name is being saved in database fine, i need help with uploading it on server

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://blog.offbeatmammal.com/post/2005/11/19/Upload-and-resize-and-image-in-ASPNET.aspx for a sample that will upload a file to the server. Once uploaded you can take the assigned filename and store that in your DB table